# High E string on tele has "sitar tone"

Tags: setup

I have a Nash Tele with the Bigsby B5 trem, which uses a jazzmaster style bridge and saddles. I have raised the action twice by adjusting the truss rod, but still get a tinny sitar like tone on the high e. Are these saddles prone to this, and will raising the saddle help? This is a brand new guitar, no fret wear at all, and Nash has a good reputation for quality work

Comment: Is this only on the open string, on all notes, or on some specific notes?

Comment: Have you considered that this could be a problem with the nut or the string tree, at the headstock? Also, if it's brand-new, you should be under warranty from Nash Guitars, so they should cover the cost of repairs by a qualified luthier or guitar repair shop. http://www.nashguitars.com/faq.html#faq3

Comment: Are all your frets level? Does the e string buzz when you are not fretting?

Comment: He'll most likely be fretting until the problem's solved...

Answer (score 3):

Can't see why adjusting the action via the trussrod would be the solution.That will move every string, when probably 5/6 were o.k. anyway. The tiny Allen screws on that particular saddle will raise that string independently. As Bob asks, where specifically does the problem manifest itself? If only when open, it's likely to be the nut slot. If only on two or three frets, it's likely to be a fret wire just too high - the one on which the noise stops occurring.If it's all over, then the string is too low against the fingerboard, and individual adjustment as above should fix it. The bottom line is as Wheat states - take it back !